# namedParameterjdbcTemplate giving nullpointer exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have been making a simple a program to add a row in the data base using jdbc and spring in a maven project I have made the project watching videos as I am new to spring and database.

```
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package com.mariam.employee;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
/** 
*
* @author shoaib kiani
*/
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao{

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedPJT;
JdbcTemplate jt;

public SqlParameterSource getSqlP(Employee e)
{
MapSqlParameterSource m=new  MapSqlParameterSource();

m.addValue("id", e.getID());
m.addValue("FirstName",e.getFirstName());
m.addValue("LastName",e.getLastName());
return m;}
@Override
public void save(Employee e) {
final String sql="INSERT INTO authors('FirstName','LastName') VALUE(?,? )";

namedPJT.update(sql , getSqlP(e));
System.out.println("Passed");



}

}
```

This is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mariam.employee.EmployeeDaoImpl.save(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:38)
at com.mariam.employee.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: ``namedPJT`` is ``null``.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedPJT;
JdbcTemplate jt;
```

To this:

```
@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedPJT;
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jt;
```